# How to build multiple projects (maven and scala) using batch file

Tags: java, scala, maven, batch-file, sbt

I am trying to build maven project as well as scala project together one by one using a windows batch file. For this I have created a batch file in the root folder and written following lines inside it. Although my maven projects are building successfully but the scala project are failing to build.

```
call mvn -f A/pom.xml clean install -U
call sbt B\build.sbt clean compile -U
call mvn -f C/pom.xml clean install -U
call sbt D\build.sbt clean compile -U
```

The error I am getting is:

```
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, 
or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 
'shell'
[info] Set current project to my project(in build file:/C:/sample-
project/MyProject/)
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: B
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: B
[error] B\build.sbt
[error]            ^
```

Comment: I don't think you can compile a scala project with sbt from outside the root. I mean `sbt your_project/build.sbt clean compile` won't work AFAIK, you have to `cd your_project; sbt clean compile`

Comment: I have modified the batch file accordingly...
But after it builds project B, It is getting stopped. 

call mvn -f A/pom.xml clean install -U
cd B
sbt clean compile
cd ../
call mvn -f C/pom.xml clean install -U
cd D
sbt clean compile

Comment: Get yourself a CI server and build each project separately. Coupling all builds together is not a good idea for many reasons.

Comment: unfortunately I donot have CI setup in my environment and using a batch file I was trying to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]

The following worked for me...

```
cd A
call mvn clean install -U
echo Completed building A
cd ..
cd B
call mvn clean install -U
echo Completed building B
cd ..
cd C
call sbt clean compile -U
echo Completed building C
cd ../
cd D
call mvn clean install -U
echo Completed building D
cd ..
cd E  
sbt clean compile
echo Completed building E
```